# Hibernate Custom Annotation for Local Variables

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, annotations

I'm trying to create a custom annotation for local variables that pretty much do the same thing as `@NotNull` `@NotEmpty` and `@NotBlank`. I can't use those annotations since they don't apply for local variables so I decided to make my own annotation. Here's the annotation:

```
import controllers.validation.validator.NotNullOrEmptyValidator;

import javax.validation.Constraint;
import javax.validation.Payload;
import javax.validation.ReportAsSingleViolation;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;
import java.lang.annotation.*;

import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.ANNOTATION_TYPE;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.FIELD;
import static java.lang.annotation.ElementType.LOCAL_VARIABLE;

@Target(LOCAL_VARIABLE)
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Documented
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotNullOrEmptyValidator.class)
@ReportAsSingleViolation
public @interface NotNullOrEmpty {
    String message() default "something is wrong!";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    @Target(LOCAL_VARIABLE)
    @Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
    @Documented
    @interface List {
        NotNullOrEmpty[] value();
    }
}
```

And here's the validator:

```
import controllers.validation.constraints.NotNullOrEmpty;

import javax.validation.ConstraintValidator;
import javax.validation.ConstraintValidatorContext;

public class NotNullOrEmptyValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNullOrEmpty, Object> {
    @Override
    public void initialize(NotNullOrEmpty constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean isValid(Object value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        return value!=null && !value.toString().isEmpty();
    }
}
```

But for some reason when I try to use it like this:

```
public class Foo {
    public void doSomething(HttpServletRequest request) {
        @NotNullOrEmpty(message = "headerpiece cannot be empty or null.")
        String headerPiece = request.get("something");
    }
}
```

It just doesn't fire. I've tried passing in that `something` value in the header with an empty string and tried not passing it in at all but the annotation just doesn't fire and neither does the validator. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure it is deployed as a webapp. In my case it is not firing for test cases but gets fired in actual web application.